# Primefaces - disable dragging in p:log

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, draggable

I am trying to use [`<p:log>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/log.xhtml) in my web application but I do not want it to be a draggable component. How can I fix it as a component inside a [`<p:panelGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml) ?

I use Primefaces 6.0 and JSF 2.2.